# I dont know how to run exists magento project on local server

Tags: php, magento

Im new with magento2 , I have full files for project how can i test the website on my pc using xampp ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below step for magento project in local server

1. Copy your project in Your xammp install drive folder -> xampp\htdocs
2. Go to phpmyadmin & import db following your project app\etc dbname
3. After importing db & composer update in your project root
4. Now browers http://127.0.0.1/your_project_name
5. Also if you need change url from db. You can change from db table core_config_data change value web/unsecure/base_url & web/secure/base_url value set your project url http://127.0.0.1/your_project_name
6. Enjoy Magento

Comment: may you explain step #3 please

Comment: Hello,
Did you install composer ? If you installed go to your project folder with cmd-> then run command composer update